# R Studio Crashes when Crosstable function runs

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm having an issue with R Studio crashing when I run the Crosstable function.  First, I'm installing the following packages:

```
install.packages ("gmodels"); install.packages("MASS")
library (gmodels); library (MASS)
```

Then, I run the following code on my data frame:

```
CrossTable(dat$PopSize, dat$PCIncChange, fisher = TRUE, chisq = TRUE)
expected = TRUE, sresid = TRUE, format="SPSS")
```

R produces the table, but then does not allow me to execute any other code in the console.  It also doesn't allow me to save my file or quit the program (I've had to use control alt delete every time).

-- Edit: Adding session info from comments --

```
sessionInfo(): 
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 
locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252 [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252; LC_NUMERIC=C [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
attached base packages: [1] splines stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base –
other attached packages: [1] MASS_7.3-23 gmodels_2.15.3 Hmisc_3.10-1 survival_2.36-14 stringr_0.6.2 
loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] cluster_1.14.3 gdata_2.12.0 grid_2.15.2 gtools_2.7.0 lattice_0.20-10 tools_2.15.2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The function itself works fine for me - you haven't told us anything about your data though.  Please provide the output of `sessionInfo()` and more info about your data.

Comment: sessionInfo(): R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252; LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
attached base packages: [1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

Comment: (Cont'd):other attached packages: [1] MASS_7.3-23      gmodels_2.15.3   Hmisc_3.10-1     survival_2.36-14 stringr_0.6.2   
loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] cluster_1.14.3  gdata_2.12.0    grid_2.15.2     gtools_2.7.0    lattice_0.20-10 tools_2.15.2

Comment: The data frame is many columns by 100 rows; some columns are numeric and others are characters.  In the crosstab function I'm running, the first column is a character, the latter is numeric.  I will try the installation solution and let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: ...It's still doing the same thing.

Comment: @JeremyStrauss - Add that information to the question itself... it's horribly formatted in the comments and other users shouldn't have to dig through the comments to understand your question.

Comment: Try running this on a subset of your data. Maybe just a few rows or columns to start with. This will help to identify if there is just one rogue value messing things up, or if you are having trouble with heap space, or if the function itself is causing problems in your current environment. Also, try running CrossTable on a standard dataset (R comes with many).

Comment: Thanks everyone -- all of these solutions seemed to freeze the program, so I think I need to reinstall R Studio.